# What is the possible cause of System Freezing?

Tags: windows-7, freeze

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate ( 64-bit ) .

Recently the system freeze twice randomly. The symptom is:

1. Num Lock no response
2. Keyboard & Mouse no response
3. Fans keep running
4. The screen is displaying, no corruption of screen ( no error )
5. No beep codes
6. Hardware reset button has no effect
7. Short press of power button has no effect
8. Long press of power button will power off the sytem
9. Next reboot, Windows 7 hints me to enter Safe Mode, but I "Start Windows Normally"
10. No extra error messages
11. System is not overheat ( just ~ 40 degree celcius )

Computer Specification:

- Intel i5 4 core
- 16GB RAM
- NVIDIA GT610
- 4 SATA HDD
- 800W PSU

What else can I check ? `eventvwr` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When keyboard no longer works, you have a hardware issue. MS explained here 5 steps to check:

**Windows Kernel event ID 41 error "The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first" in Windows 7**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2028504#method3

> To help isolate the problem, check the following items:
>
> **Overclocking:** Disable overclocking to see whether the issue occurs when the system is run at the correct speed.
>
> **Check the memory:** Verify the memory by using a memory checker. Verify that each memory chip is the same speed and that it is
>   configured correctly in the system.
>
> **Power supply:** Make sure that the power supply has enough wattage to appropriately handle the installed devices. If you added memory,
>   installed a newer processor, installed additional drives, or added
>   external devices, such devices can require more energy than the
>   current power supply can provide consistently.
>
> **Overheating:** Check whether the system is overheating by examining the internal temperature of the hardware.
>
> **Defaults:** Reset the system back to the system defaults to see whether the issues occur when the system is running in its default
>   configuration.

Comment: Thanks for referring me to Microsoft's diagnostic steps. I got no Overclocking & Overheating. For Power supply, which tool I can use to check ? For memory, can I use MEMTEST86+ ? Resetting to System Defaults, means BIOS ?

Comment: a lock that affects the keyboard indicates that the kernel is locked. the cause is often hardware, but bad drivers and corrupt system files can cause the same issues.

Comment: memtest86 is a great tool, but Windows can sometimes be finicky about ram. I've had sticks that presented no errors, but caused problems with installing and booting windows. the MS RAM diagnostic tool however reported that they were not optimal chips for windows before it even began checking the memory sectors.

Comment: @FrankThomas That is correct. Even the numlock on/off requires code in the USB stack and the kernel. If the kernel is locked up then that stuff won't work.